# Get User Address By Drag & Drop marker on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a map on my website, in which i have to get user address by just dragging & drop marker onto any place on map. I have successfully display a map on my website. But i have no idea of How to Show that marker on map which can be dragged & get User addess by that. I have below code of maps which is getting user address by clicking on map. Thanks.

```
<div id='map-canvas'></div>

var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 10,
  center: myLatlng
}

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
  geocoder.geocode({
    'latLng': event.latLng
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (results[0]) {
        alert(results[0].formatted_address);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add  a marker and a listener on drag end

in this  sample the listner  show the drag end lat, lng and performe geocode

```
<div id='map-canvas'></div>

var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 10,
  center: myLatlng
}

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    draggable:true,
    title:"Drag me!"
});

marker.addListener('dragend', function(event)  {
    alert(event.latLng.lat() + ' ' +  event.latLng.lng());
    geocoder.geocode({
    'latLng': event.latLng
    }, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        if (results[0]) {
          alert(results[0].formatted_address);
        }
      }
    });
});


google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
  geocoder.geocode({
    'latLng': event.latLng
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (results[0]) {
        alert(results[0].formatted_address);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just found answer on google documentation which is similar to your answer. But it is not giving me exact address while i placed marker somewhere.